React JS deleting nested comments
I am studying  nested comments functionality in React JS. I have trouble deleting nested comments. Basically every comment has a property replies, which is array of objects (exactly same comment object as the parent ones).
When I try to update the parent state in the inner loop (updateCommentsData(parentStateCopy);) with copied and modified array of objects it throws me this error:
updateCommentsData is not a function even though modified array of objects seems to be correct when console logging it.
State in App component:
let [commentsData, updateCommentsData] = useState();
let [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();

async function getData() {
   const path = "./src/data/data.json";
   try {
     const req = await fetch(path);
     const res = await req.json();
     updateCommentsData(res.comments);
     setCurrentUser(res.currentUser);
   } catch (e) {
     console.log("Error: " + e.message);
   }
 }

Delete function:
let repliesStateCopy = [];
let parentStateCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(commentsData));

function deleteComment(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < commentsData.length; i++) {
    if (commentsData[i].id === id) {
      updateCommentsData((prev) => {
        return prev.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
      });
      break;
    } else {
      if (commentsData[i].replies.length !== 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < commentsData[i].replies.length; j++) {
          repliesStateCopy.push(commentsData[i].replies[j]);
          if (commentsData[i].replies[j].id === id) {
            repliesStateCopy = repliesStateCopy.filter(
              (item) => item.id !== id
            );
            parentStateCopy[i].replies = repliesStateCopy;
            updateCommentsData(parentStateCopy);
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

JSON Data looks like that:
{
  "currentUser": {
    "image": {
      "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
      "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
    },
    "username": "juliusomo"
  },
  "comments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "content": "Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.",
      "createdAt": "1 month ago",
      "score": 12,
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.webp"
        },
        "username": "amyrobson"
      },
      "replies": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "content": "Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!",
      "createdAt": "2 weeks ago",
      "score": 5,
      "user": {
        "image": {
          "png": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png",
          "webp": "./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.webp"
        },
        "username": "maxblagun"
      },
      "replies": [
        {
          "id": 3,
          "content": "If you're still new, I'd recommend focusing on the fundamentals of HTML, CSS, and JS before considering React. It's very tempting to jump ahead but lay a solid foundation first.",
          "createdAt": "1 week ago",
          "score": 4,
          "replyingTo": "maxblagun",
          "user": {
            "image": {
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-ramsesmiron.webp"
            },
            "username": "ramsesmiron"
          },
          "replies": []
        },
        {
          "id": 4,
          "content": "I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.",
          "createdAt": "2 days ago",
          "score": 2,
          "replyingTo": "ramsesmiron",
          "user": {
            "image": {
              "png": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png",
              "webp": "./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.webp"
            },
            "username": "juliusomo"
          },
          "replies": []
        }
      ]
    },


What is updateCommentsData?

What is updateCommentsData? Please [edit] to include a complete [mcve] of the relevant code you are working with so readers here can better understand your post.

I am sorry. It is state holding array of objects from JSON file. let [commentsData, updateCommentsData] = useState();

@DariusMolotokas Can you provide a MRE via codepen or another sandbox so we can see what the code does for ourselves? It is hard to guesstimate from reading this

Full code here: https://github.com/dariusmit/comments

I think problem is updateCommentsData is being called directly with parentStateCopy rather than using the state setter function's callback pattern (prev => newState).
Try this code :
  const deleteComment = (commentId) => {
  setComments(prevComments => {
    const deleteRecursively = (comments) => {
      return comments.reduce((acc, comment) => {
        if (comment.id === commentId) return acc;
        return [...acc, {
          ...comment,
          replies: deleteRecursively(comment.replies)
        }];
      }, []);
    };
    
    return deleteRecursively(prevComments);
  });
};


Thanks for the answer! I've used recursion to render comments replies, but It's a little bit hard for me to understand your code. Could you explain what you did there a little bit so a newbie like me could understand? Thanks!

I've actually noticed that I forgot to pass updateCommentsData function as a prop to CommentsCard component when rendering replies. The error is gone, but deleting nested comments still does not work ( Now it jus does nothing, with your code or mine), only able to delete parent comments. That's why Typescript is better, that would never happen in TS :).

Found the solution. The problem was that I was creating 2 separate states for parent comments and for replies and rendered them individually. Like this:
Comments List component
function CommentsList({ commentsData, updateCommentsData, currentUser }) {
  return (
    <>
      {commentsData &&
        commentsData.length !== 0 &&
        commentsData.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <div className="p-4" key={comment.id}>
              <CommentsCard
                comment={comment}
                updateCommentsData={updateCommentsData}
                currentUser={currentUser}
                commentsData={commentsData}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}

And then inside CommentsCard Component I would have this state:
 let [reply, updateReply] = useState(comment.replies);

and render it like this:
  {reply &&
        reply.length !== 0 &&
        reply.map((reply) => {
          return (
            <div key={reply.id} className="pl-6 pt-4">
              <CommentsCard
                comment={reply}
                currentUser={currentUser}
                commentsData={commentsData}
                updateCommentsData={updateCommentsData}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}

Then when I tried to update the replies state it actually updated just not rendered on the screen. This delete function now does the job:
 const parentStateCopy = structuredClone(commentsData);
  function deleteComment(id) {
    for (let i = 0; i < commentsData.length; i++) {
      if (commentsData[i].id === id) {
        updateCommentsData((prev) => {
          return prev.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        });
        break;
      } else {
        if (commentsData[i].replies.length !== 0) {
          for (let j = 0; j < commentsData[i].replies.length; j++) {
            if (commentsData[i].replies[j].id === id) {
              parentStateCopy[i].replies = parentStateCopy[i].replies.filter(
                (item) => item.id !== id
              );
              updateCommentsData(parentStateCopy);
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

and this is how I render the comments and replies in CommentsList component now:
function CommentsList({ commentsData, updateCommentsData, currentUser }) {
  return (
    <>
      {commentsData &&
        commentsData.length !== 0 &&
        commentsData.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <div className="p-4" key={comment.id}>
              <CommentsCard
                comment={comment}
                updateCommentsData={updateCommentsData}
                currentUser={currentUser}
                commentsData={commentsData}
              />
              {comment.replies &&
                comment.replies.length !== 0 &&
                comment.replies.map((reply) => {
                  return (
                    <div key={reply.id} className="pl-6 pt-4">
                      <CommentsCard
                        comment={reply}
                        updateCommentsData={updateCommentsData}
                        currentUser={currentUser}
                        commentsData={commentsData}
                      />
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}

